# An effective way to lookup duplicate nodes in Neo4j 1.8?

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to programmatically locate all duplicate nodes in a Neo4j 1.8 database (using Neo4j 1.8). 
The nodes that need examination all have a (non-indexed) property `externalId` for which I want to find duplicates of. This is the Cypher query I've got:

```
            START n=node(*), dup=node(*) WHERE 
                HAS(n.externalId) AND HAS(dup.externalId) AND 
                n.externalId=dup.externalId AND 
                ID(n) < ID(dup) 
                RETURN dup
```

There are less than 10K nodes in the data and less than 1K nodes with an `externalId`.
The query above is working but seems to perform badly. Is there a less memory consuming way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
START n=node(*)
WHERE HAS(n.externalId)
WITH n.externalId AS extId, COLLECT(n) AS cn
WHERE LENGTH(cn) > 1
RETURN extId, cn;
```

It avoids taking the Cartesian product of your nodes. It finds the distinct `externalId` values, collects all the nodes with the same id, and then filters out the non-duplicated ids. Each row in the result will contain an externalId and a collection of the duplicate nodes with that id.

Answer (score 2):

The start clause consists of a full graph scan, then assembling a cartesian product of the entire set of nodes (10k * 10k = 100m pairs to start from), and then narrows that very large list down based on criteria in the where clause. (Maybe there are cypher optimizations here? I'm not sure)

I think adding an index on externalId would be a clear win and may provide enough of a performance gain for now, but you  could also look at finding duplicates in a different way, perhaps something like this:

```
START n=node(*)
WHERE HAS(n.externalId)
WITH n
ORDER BY ID(n) ASC 
WITH count(*) AS occurrences, n.externalId AS externalId, collect(ID(n)) AS ids
WHERE occurrences > 1
RETURN externalId, TAIL(ids)
```

Comment: Your first query won't work, since `n` and `dup` will always be the same node, so `id(n) > id(dup)` will always be false.

Comment: When I try this I get an error stating _string matching regex \`$' expected but \`O' found_