# Explanation of WITH and COLLECT in following duplicate finding query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was recently researching, how to find duplicate nodes by a property and found the following results which provided a very effective solution:
[neo4j find all nodes with matching properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16925829)
[An effective way to lookup duplicate nodes in Neo4j 1.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28307720)

Since I'm using Neo4j v2.2.3 Community, I used the following style:

```
match (n:Label) with n.prop as prop, collect(n) as nodelist, count(*) as count where count > 1 return prop, nodelist, count
```

I'm having trouble understanding how this works. I've spent my career using relational databases and just don't get the grouping mechanism, which is obviously there since I got a list of nodes and their respective count.

Can someone please explain how this works or provide a reference to an explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's the relevant documentation on aggregation in cypher](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-aggregation.html#aggregation-introduction).

The important bit is this:

> Aggregate functions take multiple input values and calculate an
>   aggregated value from them. Examples are avg that calculates the
>   average of multiple numeric values, or min that finds the smallest
>   numeric value in a set of values.
>
> Aggregation can be done over all the matching subgraphs, or it can be
>   further divided by introducing key values. These are non-aggregate
>   expressions, that are used to group the values going into the
>   aggregate functions.
>
> So, if the return statement looks something like this:
>
> RETURN n, count(*)
>
> We have two return expressions: n, and count(*). The first, n, is no
>   aggregate function, and so it will be the grouping key. The latter,
>   count(*) is an aggregate expression. So the matching subgraphs will be
>   divided into different buckets, depending on the grouping key. The
>   aggregate function will then run on these buckets, calculating the
>   aggregate values.
>
> If you want to use aggregations to sort your result set, the
>   aggregation must be included in the RETURN to be used in your ORDER
>   BY.

Your query is reasonably straightforward:

```
match (n:Label) 
with n.prop as prop, 
     collect(n) as nodelist, 
     count(*) as count 
where count > 1 
return prop, nodelist, count
```

You're just doing your aggregation in your `with` block instead of in your `return` block.   In this case, `collect()` isn't an aggregate function (I know, the terminology seems a bit strange) but `count(*)` is.   So your query gets divided into different buckets depending on the grouping key; your query is a little bit odd here in that `prop` would appear to be your grouping key.  Not sure if you intend that, it depends on the semantics of your query.

Comment: That clears it up a bit. The grouping in cypher is implicit when a grouping function is used to return an expression, as expressed in the first part of the 11.5 documentation. I just jumped straight to the function definition and missed that.